# make4ht multiple files hyperref issues with labels at the top of the file

Tags: hyperref, htlatex, make4ht, multiple-files, xr-hyper

The following compiles with `make4ht` but `htlatex` throws some errors. I'm trying to use make4ht to handle multiple files and link between them using `xr-hyper` and `hyperref`. In some cases I want to link to particular sections, equations etc, but in other cases I just want to link to the document. To do this I've set up a typical document that looks something like this, saved as `main.tex`

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 

%hyperlinks and referencing
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\title{Main file}

\begin{document}
\maketitle \label{main file}
\section{First Section} 
\begin{equation} \label{equation}
    \int f(x) dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The idea of the label just after the title is so that it can be linked to from other files, with out specifying a particular section, equation or theorem etc. In another file, if I have something like

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 

%hyperlinks and referencing
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\externaldocument[main-]{main}

\begin{document}
    \hyperref[main-main file]{the main file}
\end{document}
```

Then `htlatex` gives errors of the form

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: ref.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./ref.tex    34   Argument of \xr:rEfLiNK has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./ref.tex    34   Paragraph ended before \xr:rEfLiNK was complete.
```

This isn't an issue with only one file, and the output produced is as expected even with the errors, but in examples with lots of files referencing each other there seems to be too many errors for make4ht to handle. The above example works well with `pdflatex`.

There are no issues if the equation or section is labeled and referenced instead of the label after the title.

Is there a better way to link to the whole document, rather than using a label at the top of the page? I suppose what I've written above isn't best practice as the `\label`  after the title doesn't actually have anything to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so simple. TeX4ht needs to insert a destination link for label to the document, which it usually does in sectioning command, or other command that declares an object for cross-references. When you use `\label` at the beginning of the document, no such command had been called, so there is no destination. Other issue is that when you use Hyperref, every cross-reference needs to have assigned some special macros.

I would change your main document in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 

%hyperlinks and referencing
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentdoc[1]{\edef\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#1}}
\makeatother
      

\title{Main file}

\begin{document}
\maketitle \currentdoc{main file}
\section{First Section} 
\begin{equation} \label{equation}
    \int f(x) dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I've changed first `\label` to `\currentdoc`. Now in a config file, you can redefine this command to have a necessary form for TeX4ht:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
\renewcommand\currentdoc[1]{%
% the value of \@currentlabel is not important in our case, so we can just use the parameter
\edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
% these two are needed to fix hyperref errors
\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
\gdef\NR:Type{doc}%
% insert link destination to the document
\AnchorLabel%
% and now you can call label
\label{#1}%
}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I've added some comments to the code, I hope that it makes sense.

Now you can compile the main file using:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg main.tex
```

After that, the `main.aux` file should be safe for inclusion from other files.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, this works well and thanks for explaining the code. Do you know whether this is similar to how pdflatex handles this?

Comment: @holmes I don't know how it is handled in normal XR, but with TeX4ht we need make some extra steps sometimes, unfortunately.